# Where is the frame information in a time derivative of a physical vector in a moving frame using limits?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, reference-frames, differentiation

In the equation:

$$\left(\!\frac{d \vec r}{dt}\!\right)_{\!1}=
\left(\!\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\!\right)_{\!0} + \vec\omega_{01}\wedge\vec r$$

How could this be translated to a mathematical definition of limits?

My question is what is the definition of $\left(\!\frac{d\vec r}{dt}\!\right)_{\!1}$ using limits? 
And in that limit, what is the part of the limit where we indicate that the limit is differentiated with respect to the frame 1?

Considering the velocity vector as an example, if we define it as a limit it would be:

$\frac{d\overrightarrow{r}}{dt}=\underset{\Delta t\rightarrow0}{lim}\frac{\overrightarrow{r}(x,y,z,t+\Delta t)-\overrightarrow{r}(x,y,z,t)}{\Delta t}$

so

if we  write $\left(\frac{d\overrightarrow{r}}{dt}\right)_{1}=lim$

My question is how it would be the limit and in that limit in which part the frame with respect we are differentiating (in this case with respect to frame 1) is indicated.

Comment: It would follow by expressing (x1, y1, z1) in terms of their values in the rotating frame then imposing the limit.  I believe many mechanics books do this to derive the above expression.  Try Goldstien.

Comment: Hi ggcg. Thanks for your a answer. As I explained in the question I am not interested in how to get to this result. As you say you can find this in a classical book of mechanics. My question is how is that represented with the concept of limits and in those limits in what part of the notation is indicated the frame you are deriving with respect to.

Comment: It seems to me that you are being somewhat "circular" in your comment.  You want to see how it's represented as limits, but this would be in the derivation.  At least that is what I meant to say.  If not that then what am I missing?

Comment: I have edited the question. Maybe now it is clearer what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

You would define the limit as
$$ \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} = \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\vec{r}(t+\Delta t) - \vec{r}(t)}{\Delta t}.$$

If the velocities in question are fields and not the velocities of a single object, then you would include the spatial coordinates as arguments in $\vec{r}$.

What indicates what reference frame you are calculating the limits or derivatives for has little to do with how you calculate the limit. It is not only the time derivatives of the position vectors (i.e. velocities) that are different for the two reference frames, but also the position vectors themselves. $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_0 $ (and also $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_0$) are different vectors with different components (i.e. each is a different vector-valued function of time), even though they describe the motion of the same object. This is because they represent this motion in different coordinate systems.

Comment: I have edited the questing because it had a mistake that I think led you to this answer. My question is in which part of the limit I am expressing that the derivative is with respect to one frame or another.

Comment: I don't believe I misunderstood the question, unless I'm misunderstanding it now. The information on what frame you are calculating velocities for is implicit in the positions you are differentiating. They have different components in each frame. If you have an object that is stationary in one reference frame (constant position vector), the position may have time-varying components in a frame that is rotating relative to the first frame. If you express the positions as functions of time, you will get two different functions. After that, there is no difference in the process of differentiation.